# TRIAC dimming using MOC3021 with two or more lights are connected, in off condition lights is some blow

Tags: microcontroller, power-electronics, opto-isolator, triac, dimming

In this dimming circuit I'm using BTA41/BTA16/BTA39 and MOC3021.

There is 1 light is dimming is running smoothly, but when 2 or more light is connected, in off condition lights are blowing dim. Where is the problem? I can not find.
Light is 25 W, 30 W.

I'm using zero cross detector using MOC3021, is there any problem from software side?
Or any changes needed in hardware component value?

Is there any resistor power ratings are higher needed?
Also, I have added snubber circuit parallel to TRIAC 2 points, between line and offline, snubber circuit - 47E, 1 watt and 0.1 uF capacitor .

[image: Snubber Circuit]

[image: Triac Dimming Circuit]

Comment: Is TR1 signal DC or AC?  Make sure TR1 is not doing anything unexpected.

Comment: TR1 is signal from Microcontroller which operated through 3.3V

Comment: Please write to the best of your ability and run your test though a word processor before posting. Still, many things are nor clear, _"BTA41/BTA16/BTA39"_. Which one of the three? _"between line and offline"_ What's offline? Neutral? _"blowing dim"_ Is that glowing dim?

Comment: Now I m using BTA12 and also BTA16 , In both Condition connection Between Line and Offline

Answer (score 1):

First, let's look at the zero crossing detector. So it is too slow and therefore unsafe. It can be significantly improved by replacing the resistors. I don't know why it works from 5 V when I read later about a 3.3 V CPU. It doesn't matter, because the waveforms will be similar at 3.3 V.
[image]
[image]

Switching on the MOC3021 requires a significantly higher current (min. 15 mA). Uncertain control can cause high-frequency disturbances in the system. Recommended operating IF lies between max IFT (15 mA for MOC3021) and absolute max IF (60 mA).

In this circuit the “hot” side of the line is switched and the load connected to the cold or ground side. This also works the other way around, only this way is more expedient.

[image]
[image]
The 39 Ω resistor and 10 nF capacitor are for snubbing of the triac, and the 360 Ω resistor and 47 nF capacitor are for snubbing the optocoupler. The latter is more important because the optocoupler has a lower operating voltage than the triac.

Comment: I also Try Your circuit , but still light is glow  in off condition , what is exact problem ? I did't find , if there any solution ?

Comment: If the control (synchronization) is good, I can only think of excessive input mains voltage disturbances. This can be improved with a higher voltage optocoupler (600 V instead of 400 V).

Comment: In filament bulb Working Properly , but In  Dimmable Led light problem is occurred .

Comment: This is a completely different problem. The current of the switched-off TRIAC is not zero, and the consumption of the snubber circuits is added to this. This current starts to charge the capacitor of the LED power supply when it is switched off, and above a certain voltage the LED lights up until it discharges the capacitor. So, in order for this to work with TRIAC control, it is necessary to have a resistor in parallel with the LED lights.
We use the existing 47 k resistors as a test, if it only delays the flashes, then a smaller value is needed.

Comment: Parallel with led lights means load and line ? or load and neutral ?
can u draw me for better understanding

Comment: The resistor should be where Rload (470) is on my schematic. Instead of a resistor, a low-power conventional light bulb can also be used.

Comment: I have tried all but still not getting solutions ?

Comment: Not all dimmable LED lamps are [Triac dimmable](https://www.manufacturer.lighting/club/17/). You can only use a Triac dimmable lamp or a Triac dimmable LED power supply.

Comment: Yes , You are right , but in my condition , When snubber circuit is not attached , Dimming is perfect working but flickering Problem is there

Comment: 1. When the snubber circuit is not attached, the dimming functionality works perfectly during the on and off conditions. No light is dimmed in the off state, which is the desired behavior. However, there is an issue of flickering in this scenario.
2. When the snubber circuit is attached, the problem of flickering is resolved, which is a positive outcome. However, a new problem arises where the light remains dimmed in the off condition, which is not the intended behavior.

Comment: Given these observations, it is clear that there are trade-offs between having a functioning dimming feature and eliminating flickering. While the snubber circuit resolves the flickering problem, it introduces the unintended consequence of dimmed lighting in the off state.

Comment: In this case, try to reduce the value of the capacitors of the snubber circuits to see if there will be a problem-free state. The value of the capacitors could even be reduced to a tenth of the current values.

Comment: I have used the circuit u posted in answer , with 47 k resistor , but when i used 2 different circuits , dimming is proper running but , when the dimming light is off and other i on/off other normal load , then Dimming light is turn on/off for 1sec , is there any solution for that @csabahu

Comment: From this I think that the internal resistance of the 230V network is too high (thin, long wires). Thus, turning on an additional load results in a large voltage transient. Maybe it could help
Use of [AC EMI filters](https://www.schurter.com/en/products-and-solutions/catalog?(pg84)/1) either at the plus consumer or before both triac circuits.

Comment: can u explain why r1 is 68k  on interrupt pin? can i place 10k instead of 68k ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is firing your TRIAC. Verify to have connected the snubber as in the old application note from [OnSemi](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN-3008.pdf) (see page 10)

[EDIT]
Page 10 of the document is page **12** in the PDF, just to clarify; see **figure 22**.